# If $h_u \times_G F$ is representable for every $u \in \text{Ob}(C)$ and $G$ is representable then so is $F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, functors, fibre-product

This is from the [Stacks Project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0021).

I have so far the following pullback squares:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
D @>{Q}>> C^{op}\\
@V{P}VV @V{H}VV \\
C^{op} @>{h_u \times_G F}>> \text{Sets}
\end{CD}
\ \ \ \ \  \ 
\begin{CD} 
E @>{Q'}>> C^{op} \\
@V{P'}VV @V{H'}VV \\
C^{op} @>{G}>> \text{Sets}
 \end{CD}
\ \ \ \ \ \ 
\begin{CD}
(h_u \times_G F)(x) @>{q_x}>> F(x) \\
@V{p_x}VV @V{g_x}VV \\
h_u(x) @>{f_x}>> G(x)
\end{CD} \forall x \in \text{Ob}(C)
$$

where $h_u \times_G F$ means $ h_u \times_{\xi, G, a} F$ for every $\xi \in G(u)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u$ be a representing object for $G$ and $v$ be a representing object for $h_u \times_G F$. Then,

$$ \begin{align}
F &\cong G \times_{G} F \cong h_u \times_G F \cong h_v
\end{align}$$

---

Note that for any morphism $f$ in *any* category, the following square is a pullback:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD} X @>1_x>> X
\\ @VfVV @VVf V
\\ Y @>>1_Y> Y
\end{CD} $$
More generally, for any isomorphisms $u,v$, the following square is a pullback:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD} W @>u>> X
\\ @Vv^{-1}fuVV @VVf V
\\ Y @>>v> Z
\end{CD} $$